# General form for a parametric curve along a sphere?

Tags: parametric, parametrization

I know that for a circle, the parametric equation is $(x(t),y(t))=(\sin(t+a),\cos(t+a+\pi n))$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $a\in\mathbb R$.

I was trying to make work for a sphere, which would only cover a portion of it, and I think I got a particular solution $$(x(t),y(t),z(t))=\big(\cos(\sin(et))\sin (t),\cos(\sin(et))\cos (t),\sin(et)\big)$$

I know that $e$ can be replaced with nearly any irrational number, and I think $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ can be replace in a similar way the circle one can, but I'm not sure. I don't see what else can be generalized, but I know that it definitely can be generalized further.

Comment: Both MathWorld and Wikipedia give parametrizations for the sphere in terms of two angles. You can derive the parametrization from slicing the sphere up into circles lying in planes perpendicular to a chosen axis.